# where method not working in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, where-clause

I'm trying to use a `where` statement in laravel, but in return I'm getting a blank value.

Here's the code

```
$vehicles_make_id = $_POST['vehicles_make_id']; //getting "Audi"    
$vehicles_name_trim = $_POST['vehicles_name_trim']; //getting "A3, 2.0T Premium Automatic"

$vehicles_name_trim_ar = explode(',', $vehicles_name_trim); 

$model_name = $vehicles_name_trim_ar[0]; //getting "A3"
$model_trim = $vehicles_name_trim_ar[1]; //getting "2.0T Premium Automatic"

$vehicles_body_ar = array_filter(array_unique(Model::where('model_make_id', $vehicles_make_id)
                                                   ->where('model_name',    $model_name)
                                                   ->where('model_trim',    $model_trim)
                                                   ->lists('model_body')));

print_r(2.0T Premium Automatic);
```

I checked and the value exists in the database but I'm getting a blank array

Comment: The first thing to do is break the code down into testable bits - first off extract your Model::where bit out: `$builder = Model::where('model_make_id', $vehicles_make_id)->where('model_name', $model_name)->where('model_trim',  $model_trim)` - now you can call ->toSql() on that to get the SQL that it would execute, based on that SQL maybe you can work out why nothing's coming back.

Comment: Agree with alexrussel, you can also use the function `dd()` to _Die and Dump_ any data to the screen for debug purposes. It works in a similar way to doing `var_dump()` followed by `die()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your where's are wrong, aren't they missing '='.

```
$vehicles_body_ar = array_filter(array_unique(Model::where('model_make_id', '=', $vehicles_make_id)->where('model_name', '=', $model_name)->where('model_trim', '=',  $model_trim)->lists('model_body')));
```

**Last Query Check**

```
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
$last_query = end($queries);
print_r($last_query);
```

Comment: No, you are not required to use 3 arguments. When using 2 arguments, it will automatically be a `=` check.

Comment: Try the last query check I have added above and make sure your query checks out.